# rococo parachain stop generate blocks

Tags: substrate, polkadot, rococoa

I have encountered a problem. I recently tried to upgrade the rococo parachain. After calling the enactAuthorizedUpgrade method, it stopped generating blocks and restarting the node did not work. This is the parachain log. Can anyone help me to find out what the problem is?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmeye.png)